# Strange ghull error when using simple cv

Tags: python, simplecv, qhull

### In [2]: import SimpleCV

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\root\<ipython-input-2-d3da1d75bea1> in <module>()
----> 1 import SimpleCV

C:\Users\root\build\bdist.win32\egg\SimpleCV\__init__.py in <module>()

C:\Users\root\build\bdist.win32\egg\SimpleCV\base.py in <module>()

C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\spatial\__init__.py in <module>()
     25 from kdtree import *
     26 from ckdtree import *
---> 27 from qhull import *
     28
     29 __all__ = filter(lambda s:not s.startswith('_'),dir())

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Anyone know why am I getting this error? What is this qhull package, I don't see how to install this for python. It should come with scipy? On a different computer with python 2.6 I don't get this problem?

Update: I tried reinstalling scipy and same problem. I tracked the issue to that qhull.pyd is missing dependent DLLs, it is saying msvcr90.dll is missing but I have it in my system32 folder but it is lookign for it in the local directory? Anyone know how to change this?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like something is up with the SciPy install on your machine, I would recommend re-installing scipy with the appropriate version http://sourceforge.net/projects/scipy/files/scipy/0.10.0/.

Note that SimpleCV is compatible with python 2.6 and 2.7, but doesn't have Python 3.X support.

Answer (score 0):

Go to http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Requires Numpy-**MKL**